# how to pass async function as prop in vuejs properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

I'm trying to pass an async function as a property to a vuejs component from an external application however I'm experiencing the following issue.

Let's say in my non-vue component I define this function

```js
var myComponent = {
     myVar: "test",
     myFunc: async function (cookie) {
              console.log(this.myVar); //yields an error in the vue instance but works normally in the component
              return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                //if success
                let success = true;
                if (success) {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    resolve('Saved after 5000ms: ');
                  }, 5000);
                } else {
                  reject('An error occurred');
                }
              });
            },
    }
```

In one system I have asyncFunc1 in another asyncFunc2, they both do the same job but in a totally different way for their respective environment and both systems will initialize the same vue component with passing their own function as a prop.I cannot declare this function in the Vue component because it needs to be defined in a different way in the different external environments.

```js
var component = this;
var vm = new Vue({
            i18n,
            el: '#app',
            render(h) {
              return h(App, {
                props: {
                  myFunc: component.myFunc, //async function
                },
                ref: 'test',
              });
            },
          });
```

My Vue component will invoke this function passed via the prop before doing it's own work with its internal methods.

So my issue now is that when the function is passed as a prop, the reference to `this` changes to the Vue instance from the original Component so I can't use my function correctly. 
Supposedly Objects and functions are passed by reference in props but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Bind your function to `this` when you set it. `myFunc: component.myFunc.bind(component)`

Comment: I see, didn't think of searching for other frameworks so I couldn't find it when searching for Vue issues. Thanks a lot for spotting it.

Comment: It's not a framework specific issue, it's just that you're passing a loose reference to a function, you will always lose the `this` if you don't bind it. Happens in plain JS

Comment: Yes I understood that by reading the explanation in the other post. I just didn't know how to look up my issue to find the correct answer.